# Show that $\{0\}$ and $V$ are the only linear subspaces of $V = k.$ where $k$ is a field.

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

On the surface this seemed easy, but my first attempt was rendered useless since I don't actually know that its an ordered field. I said: Let $W (\neq V)$ be a subspace of $  V$ then, if we let $v = \max W$ ... I can't do this. I can see in terms of examples, I.e choosing $V = \mathbb{R}$ then if we take $W = [1,2]$ then it is clear to show, but again this is an ordered field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to pick a maximal element of $W$. Suppose $W$ is a nonzero subspace of $V$. Pick any nonzero element $x \in W$. Then what is the span of $x$ in $V$?

Comment: $span{x} = V$?  I see! I did not think of using that property.

Answer (score 0):

For a linear subspace we have a linear functoin $\varphi$, as we are dealing with a field we can also say it's a field homomorphism, that is $\varphi:k\to F$ for some other field $F$, all subspaces can be a kernel for some linear function and as such we have just all the possible $\ker \varphi$ being our subspaces. However again as we're dealing with a field we also know htat $\ker\varphi$ is an ideal, in fields the only ideals are $0$ and $k$ and as such those are the only possible ones.

Answer (score 0):

We can appeal to the following fact.

> **Fact.** Let $U$ be a subspace of a finite dimensional vector space $V$. Then $U$ is finite-dimensional and $\dim U\leq\dim V$. If $U$ is a proper subspace, then $\dim U<\dim V$.

A proof of this fact can be found [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Dimension_of_Proper_Subspace_Less_Than_its_Superspace).

In our case we can start by proving that $k$ is a one-dimensional vector space over itself. Then the fact above implies that every proper subspace $U$ of $k$ is zero-dimensional and thus trivial.